# C++ return vector from function by vector.resize() and vector.reserve()

Tags: c++

The `resize()` method can insert or delete appropriate number of elements to the vector to make it given size and it will affect the `size()` method. In the other hand, the reserve() method can preallocate memory for the vector container and it also allows us to insert value directly by `operator []`. When I tried to preallocate the vector container and return it by copy, I got the error. However, I can do this successfully with the vector which is initialized by `resize()` method. What is the difference between this two function?

The following is the first version, which gives me the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

class Test_Vector {
 private:
  std::vector<int> snpIndex;
 public:
  std::vector<int> test() {
    snpIndex.resize(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      snpIndex[i] = 5;
    return snpIndex;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test_Vector test_vector;
  std::vector<int> test_snp = test_vector.test();

  std::cout << test_snp.size() << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << test_snp[i] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The following is the second version, which gives me an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>

class Test_Vector {
 private:
  std::vector<int> snpIndex;
 public:
  std::vector<int> test() {
    snpIndex.reserve(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      snpIndex[i] = 5;
    return snpIndex;
  }
};

int main() {
  Test_Vector test_vector;
  std::vector<int> test_snp = test_vector.test();

  std::cout << test_snp.size() << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cout << test_snp[i] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `and it also allows us to insert value directly by operator []` It doesn't.

Comment: `reserve` does not change the size of your vector, you are assigning out of bounds